# Keeping firebase data secure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

So the last thing I want is anyone accessing the database that isn't supposed to. Users on my app create an account which has a key and children in my database (an easy to acces user profile) and it also makes an auth account. The rules of the database state that only authenticated users can access the database. Is it possible for someone who is authenticated to somehow access the rest of the database (through hacking maybe)? This is my first app using firebase and I want to make sure that user information will be protected.

Answer (score 1):

It depends by **your rules**.

If the rule is:

```
// These rules require authentication
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This kind of rule allows full read and write access to **authenticated users** of your app. In other words an authenticated user can access all the data in the database without any hacking.

If you set something similar to this rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

it grants write access to the owner of this user account but only of this data.

It means that you have to set the rules to obtain the wanted result for each nodes in your data.

Comment: If the rules are if the user is authenticated then allow read/write access they would only be allowed to edit what the app allows them to edit?

Comment: @XvKnightvX It is not secure. If you have auth to the data , you can access them in other way, just having the url of the database for example.

Comment: Ok so I would need to use something similar to that second rule set that you have in your answer. Now my app has user types (user admin owner) and there is a section of data for each individual business as well as a seperate section in the database containing a list of all users. How would I go about limiting what data a user can access based on user role?